# Find the upper bound of the derivative of an analytic function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration, integral-inequality, cauchy-integral-formula

The question is: if $f(z)$ is analytic and $|f(z)|\leq M$ for $|z|\leq r$, find an upper bound for$|f^{(n)}(z)|$ in $|z|\leq\frac{r}{2}$.

My attempt:
Since $f(z)$ is analytic where $|z|\leq r$, we know that
$$f^{(n)}(z)=\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}dw,$$
and $f(z)$ is bounded by $M$.
We know that $\bigg|\int_Cf(z)dz\bigg|\leq\max|f(z)|\cdot\text{(length of C)}$, so 
$$\bigg|f^{(n)}(z)\bigg|=\bigg|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}dw\bigg|\leq n!\cdot M_n\cdot2\pi r,$$
where $M_n:=\max|\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}|$, for a fixed $z$.

Is this correct? Just finding an upper bound seems like it shouldn't be too difficult, but I feel that I didn't do it correctly.
Also, on a somewhat related note, since $f(z)$ is analytic, and its derivatives are analytic, shouldn't $\int_{|z|=r}f^{(n)}(z)dz=0$?

Comment: $|w-z| \geq r/2$ for $|z|<r/2$. Also $2 \pi $ should be cancelled. Then you don't need $M_n$. You can just use $r/2$ and $M$ to do it.

Comment: For "$\int_{|z|=r}f^{(n)}(z)dz=0$?", yes. But you want to bound $f^{(n)}(z)$, instead of its integral. You can expect there are a lot of negative and positive part, so turn out it becomes $0$ after summing up.

Comment: Oh, that makes sense, thank you.
And what am I canceling $2\pi$ out with? And how does that get rid of $M_n$?

Comment: Because $$|\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}| \leq \frac{M}{(r/2)^{n+1}}$$. After converting it to $M$ and $r$, it becomes independent to $w$, so you can pull it out. Also, 
$$\int_{|z|=r} 1 dw = 2 \pi r$$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the right track, but the estimate is not enough.

Fix a $z$ in the Disk of $r$. Consider disk $\gamma$ centered at $z$:
$$
|w-z|=\frac{r-|z|}{\rho}
$$
where $\rho>1$ so that it is completely inside the Disk of $r$. Then
\begin{align}
\bigg|f^{(n)}(z)\bigg|&=\bigg|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}dw\bigg|
\\
&=\bigg|\frac{n!}{2\pi i}\int_{\gamma}\frac{f(w)}{(w-z)^{n+1}}dw\bigg|
\\
&\leqslant\frac{n!}{2\pi}\int_{\gamma}\frac{M}{|w-z|^{n+1}}|dw|
\\
&=\frac{M n!}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{1}{|w-z|^{n+1}}\frac{r-|z|}{\rho}d\theta
\\
&=\frac{M n!}{2\pi}\int_{0}^{2\pi}\frac{\rho^n}{(r-|z|)^{n}}d\theta
\\
&=\frac{M n!\rho^n}{(r-|z|)^{n}}
\end{align}
So in $|z|\leq\frac{r}{2}$, there is
$$
\bigg|f^{(n)}(z)\bigg|\leqslant\frac{M n!\rho^n}{(r-r/2)^{n}}=\frac{M n!(2\rho)^n}{r^{n}}
$$

Comment: What is $\rho$?

Comment: $ρ$ is any real >1, which is to make sure that $\gamma$ is within disk of r.