# Confused with Complex analysis polynomial

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Hi guys I'm quite lost with a question which I've come across.

The question is:

Let $\ p(z) = c_nz^n+c_{n-1}z^{n-1}+...+c_1z+c_0 $ be a polynomial suppose $\ \lvert p(z) \rvert \le 1$ for all $\ z \in D(0,1), $ Show that $\lvert c_k \rvert \le 1$ for all $\ k = 0,1, ... n$

I'm quiet unsure as to what I should do. Any help would be aprreciated

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1673864/find-the-upper-bound-of-the-derivative-of-an-analytic-function), noting that $c_n=p^{(n)}(0)$

Comment: @MPW Thanks for your comment! I'm sorry I'm teaching myself complex analysis I don't really understand what's happening in that question either. Am I looking for limits in this question?

Comment: Oops, should have said $c_n = p^{(n)}(0)/n!$

Comment: [Cauchy estimates](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_integral_formula#Consequences).

Answer (score 1):

$c_n = \frac {p^{(n)}(0)}{n!}$ (Taylor series)

$\frac {p^{(n)}(0)}{n!}= \frac 1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=1} \frac {p(z)}{z^n} dz$ (Cauchy integral formula)

$|\int_{|z|=1} \frac {p(z)}{z^n} dz|\le 2\pi \max (|\frac {p(z)}{z^n}|)$

$|p(z)| \le 1, |z^n| = 1, \max (|\frac {p(z)}{z^n}|) \le 1$

$|c_n| \le 1$